# SQL statement fails through mysqldb.query in Python

Tags: python, mariadb, mysql-python

I am trying to pass a query through my script, but i get a SQL error.
Running the same sql statement in Heidisql works fine.

My question is:
- What am I doing wrong?

error message

> _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
>   _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'Gabrielsen)' at line 1")

Python script where Database is the correct connection to database

```
F="Gunnar Gabrielsen"
Database.query('INSERT INTO documents (name) values (' + F + ');')
i=Database.query('SELECT * from documents;')
print(i)
```

Python version:Python 3.4

Module:Mysqldb

DB:MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't put quotes around your value.

But you should never do it this way anyway. Quite apart from the quoting problem, you are opening yourself to sql injection attacks.

Use a parametrised query instead:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO documents (name) values (%s)',  (F,))
```

Comment: Thank you, also for giving insight sqlinjection  I saw the %s, but I never understood the application of it

Answer (score 0):

You have generated this:

```
INSERT INTO documents (name) values (Gunnar Gabrielsen);
```

What you need is

```
INSERT INTO documents (name) values ("Gunnar Gabrielsen");
```

But, without escaping or parameterizing, you are opening your code (and system) up to "sql injection" and other hacking.